# 12.04 Freeze while logging in after logging out for once

Tags: 12.04, compiz, login, freeze, logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, here are my hardware specifications:

> Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 450 @ 2.40GHz × 4, 1.9 GiB, 32 bit, 77.8 GB.

I have several interfaces on my PC such as Unity(default), Gnome-Shell, Gnome2, LXDE, KDE. And I use LightDM.

**After logging out from any of these interfaces, it is impossible to login any of them normally without a reboot.** The Desktop Interface just *freezes* after entering the password. *I can see* the wallpaper, desktop icons, dash and some basic things. None of them *respond to the mouse click*. (Mouse is all right.) And I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to `sudo reboot`.

Why should I suffer this!?

I found many running `compiz` processes while it is freezing by `top`.

Comment: You're saying that compiz is installed?  If it is try to un-install.

Comment: You mean I have to unstall compiz? But itn't compiz the default window decorator for Pricise? By the way, I am quite grateful that you answered me.

Comment: Yes, try it, and see if it helps, you can always install it back.